# Pubnub messages not getting converted to JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, pubnub

According to https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043790-can-i-send-and-or-receive-json-objects- we can send JSON objects in Pubnub messages and I myself have done it my previous projects.

But this time, this thing is giving me tough time. 
On sending side what I have done is:

```
var json = [String : Any]
json["lat"] = 33.923892
json["long"] = 73.232873
json["userId"] = "abc"
```

And on receiving side I am trying to cast it as:

```
let info = message.data.message.value as! [String : Any]
```

But its crashing and giving me error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1b69af5e8) to
>   'NSDictionary' (0x1b69b04e8)

I have tried different solutions including:

1. Serializing JSON.
2. Sending array instead [String : Any].

But every time I get the same error. And yes I know that questions like *Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary'* are answered before. But none of them worked for me.

Comment: What is JSONObject? Sorry for my ignorance but it sounds like a Java class.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am sorry for not mentioning. Its just a typealias which i am using for [String : Any].

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Check now

Comment: "1. Serializing JSON", was this done using Codable and what does `message.data.message.value` contain when printing it?

Comment: I did it using JSONSerialization and it gave error of invalid input format

Comment: What is the publisher SDK? Also Swift or Java? If Java, use Gson instead of JSONObject. Let me know. Also, you can submit this to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) with [client SDK logs that capture this issue](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk-troubleshooting-guide).

Comment: Code was not working yesterday. But today when deleted derived data, clean built folder and then run it, its working all fine with [String : Any]. 
Seems like I was constantly trying different things, commenting one solution and running the other, so something went wrong with Xcode. (which is very strange)

Comment: Thank you everyone for looking into my problem and investing your time :)

Comment: Be sure to add this as an official answer and you will get more rep with SO.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
let info = message.data.message.value as! JSONObject
```

with

```
let info = message.data.message.value as! String
```

Comment: Then how can I get the values for lat long and user id which i have sent?

Comment: i guess it's a json string print the output of the above line and i will tell you